# How can I have the search option based on typing letters in pickerInput using shinyWidgets?

Tags: r, shiny

I use `pickerInput` function from the `shinyWidgets` package in Shiny to have a dropdown menu. For example part of my `ui.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(shinyWidgets)

.
.
#Rating
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "rate",
          label = "Rating:",
          choices = c(as.character(unique(datT2[order(rat.ord)]$Rating))),     
          selected = sort(unique(as.character(datT2$Rating ))),   
          options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                         `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(unique(as.character(datT2$Rating  )))-1) ,
                         `count-selected-text` = "Alle",liveSearch = TRUE, 
                         liveSearchPlaceholder= TRUE),   
          multiple = T
        )
```

before this function I applied just the normal function:

```
#Rating
  selectInput("rate",
                "Rating:",
                choices = c("Alle",
                            sort(unique(as.character(datT2$Rating )))),     
 selected = "Alle", 
 multiple = TRUE)
```

In `selectInput` function is possible to search based on typing but not possible to deselect the selected items just by click like in  `pickerInput`.

How can I have the search option based on typing letters in  `pickerInput`?

Answer (score 18):

A bit of a late answer, but your option-naming is wrong. Change `liveSearch` in `live-search` and it will work.

```
options = list(`live-search`=TRUE)
```

---

**EDIT**

If you have `shinyWidgets >= 4.4` you can also use the function `pickerOptions` for setting the options. You can check all possible options by calling `?pickerOptions` or check this [url](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/pickerOptions.html).

An example with both methods:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput('picker 1', 'picker1', c(1,2,3,4,5), options=pickerOptions(liveSearch=T)),
  pickerInput('picker 2', 'picker2', c(1,2,3,4,5), options = list(`live-search`=TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I know, I'm late to the party, but dammit you made my day!

Comment: @Georgery check the edit for the latest working method!

Comment: Ah! Actually also very helpful. Thanks.